# Problem while initializing function pointer?

Tags: c++, c

I have function pointer as follow

```
void (*stream) (const char *)
```

and im initializing the pointer as follows:

```
char dumpBuffer[512];
snprintf (dumpBuffer, sizeof (dumpBuffer), "<Pcm_DigitalIoChannelList>\n");
stream (dumpBuffer);
```

can any on tell me is is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you show does not initialize the pointer. It tries to use it without initializing it first, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Voting to close as the edit makes this nonsense.

Comment: Roll back to an earlier edit?

Answer (score 3):

To initialize this pointer, you have to assign the address of a function with a compatible signature to it:

```
void foo(const char *) {
    // do stuff
}

void (*stream) (const char *) = &foo;
```

This would work too, because functions are automatically promoted to pointers:

```
void (*stream) (const char *) = foo;
```

Then you can use it as you show above.

Answer (score 2):

not quite, generally you must define the function pointer like:

```
typedef void (*stream) (const char*);
```

then you assign it to a function:

```
stream myStream = &somefunction;
```

then you can simply run it:

```
myStream(pSomeBuffer);
```

Comment: why *must* the OP define a `typedef`?

Comment: +1. thats the best way to use that

Comment: It's not necessary but I do recommend it for code readability. Otheriwise you just directly assign the above mentioned void (*stream) (const char *) to a function